# log of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Suppose a function f has an infinte series given by $f(z) = \sum^\infty_{n=-m} a_n z^n.$ Is there an easy way to write $\ln f$ as an infinite series?

Ideally, I want $\ln f(z) = \sum^\infty_{n=-k} b_n z^n.$ where the $b_n$'s are explicit functions of $a_n$'s but basically any and all ideas which may help me tackle this problem are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

On what domain?  If there is a closed path $\gamma$ in the domain such that $f(\gamma)$ has nonzero winding number around $0$, there is no branch of $\ln f$ that is analytic in the domain.  This will be the case e.g. if the domain includes a punctured neighbourhood of $0$ and $a_n \ne 0$ for some $n < 0$.

Comment: $z=e^{2 \pi i t}$ is a complex number with $Im (t)>0$

Comment: Well, that would be a punctured disk.